# Ember.js Named outlets error

Tags: javascript, ember.js, rendering

Is there a limitation on where named outlets can be placed? My templates don't render and when I specify the `into` property I get an error. Here is the relevant code: https://gist.github.com/knownasilya/5700187

This is the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'connectOutlet' of undefined
```

Looks like `parentView` is `null` here: `parentView.connectOutlet(options.outlet, view);` (line 25461).

I'm setting the `into` property as the name of the template in which the outlet exists. Am I doing this wrong, should this be a route name (I don't have any routes for this parent view)?

Child View Route:

```
App.MapSearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render({
      into: "sidebar",
      outlet: "sidebar"
    });
  }
});
```

The outlet is here:

```
<ul class="navigation">
  <li>
    {{#linkTo map.search class="accent-blue"}}
      <i class="icon-search icon-white"></i>
    {{/linkTo}}
  </li>

  <li>
    {{#linkTo map.overlay class="accent-purple"}}
      <i class="icon-th-large icon-white"></i>
    {{/linkTo}}
  </li>

  <li>
    {{#linkTo map.contact class="accent-green"}}
      <i class="icon-envelope icon-white"></i>
    {{/linkTo}}
  </li>
</ul>

{{outlet sidebar}}
```

and that previous template is rendered in this template,which is rendered in the main outlet:

```
<div id="map"></div>
{{view App.SidebarView}}
```

Comment: Please could you share some code. Most useful will be the templates and the routes where you render templates.

Comment: @Gevious I've updated my question with some code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A great place to check for rendering help is in the [ember guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/).

You can have as many outlets as you like. Your code seems good, from what I can tell. I'm assuming you have a mapsearch template defined as well? That's the template that'll get rendered into the sidebar.

Try popping the sidebar outlet into the parent template. Since its not nested anywhere in your sidebar template, it won't make a visual difference. Make sure you change your 'into' flag when you render the template. Let me know how it works out for you.

Comment: I do have a `mapSearch` template, but unfortunately it doesn't render. I've read the guides and looked through the API. It just won't budge. I know that the template works though, because I can render it directly via `{{view App.MapSearchView}}`.

Comment: Looks like that worked. So is the issue then the fact that there is no route associated with my intermediate view? I had `MapView > SidebarView > MapOverlayView + MapSearchView + MapContactView` and only the first view and the last three children have routes, but the `SidebarView` is routeless. Seems like the parent view isn't assigned in that case.

Comment: Quite possibly. The view is self generated, but I've noticed that sometimes the self generated objects aren't quite as reliable as they could be. If you're happy, feel free to accept the answer :)